# What won't be guaranteed to run after beforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

If I listen to the beforeunload event and then run some code when I hear the event, what is guaranteed to run? I know that if I make an ajax request, the connection may be closed before I get the response. Is there anything else to be aware of? For example, if I had a big for loop, is it guaranteed that it will be fully executed before the page is closed?

Any limitations you can share would be great!!

Thanks

Comment: All synchronous operations will complete unless the user kills the browser. All asynchronous operations are never guaranteed to complete.

Comment: Great stuff, thank you! If you performed a post message into an iframe, I can see that the postmessage itself would be sent, but is it possible that a function fired by a listener in the iframe wouldn't execute entirely? I think this would be unreliable as I think only on the sending of the postmessage would be guaranteed to work. Would you agree @DarinDimitrov ? Thanks again